# I have installed sql server on my system but mssql server not connecting with php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have installed `sql server` on my system. I followed the whole procedure to install and connect it to `php`. But neither it's connecting to `php` nor I can see any section of `sqlsrv` in php info. I cannot make out what the problem is..

Can somebody pls help me out with any mistake that I might be committing.. Please Help.

Comment: The problem could be in `$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";` Also check  `php_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc9.dll` extension is installed or not.

Comment: We need to know more. Can you connect locally via MSSQL Management Studio? Did you configure a DB and setup SQL Authentication? You have not even shown us how you're trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Better to describe us an error if occurs.
Can you provide your development environments?

These below links may helpful to resolve your issues.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx
- http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php
- http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/using-the-microsoft-sql-server-driver-sqlsrv-for-php-37.html